# Boostrap container spacing left and right

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to have a container that changes with the width of the page as a bootstrap containers does, but still have gaps between the container and the sides of the page when it gets really small. Unlike how it does now where it gets to a certain smallness and then takes up the whole page.

Comment: found out why it was acting like a fluid container. Had accidentally set the max-width of the container earlier in the CSS. Removing that has now caused the media breakpoints to act correctly again

Comment: Please include the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

set container padding to 0px..

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain why this will work and how it is done (i.e. the code).

Answer (score 0):

> With the help of media queries, Bootstrap gives different widths to the .container depending on the size of the device:

```
Extra small devices (<768px): width: auto (or no width)
Small Devices (≥768px): width: 750px
Medium Devices (≥992px): width: 970px
Larger Devices (≥1200px): width: 1170px
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta write a media query at the wanted breakpoint and customize the container of BS4. For example

```
@media screen and (max-width:425px){
   .container{
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code within your media query breakpoint.put a your css after bootstrap css.

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```